# Not letting me post an answer when I have more than 10 reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have a rep of 101, but I still get this at the bottom where one would usually post an answer:

[image]

Comment: I just came here to ask the same! I can't see a "post an answer" area on protected question requiring minimum 10rep. But I have more than 100. I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to answer a protected question

The notice tries to convey that by saying "on this site" but I can see how that isn't clear.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking this was the case. But in my opinion this is clearly a bug (i.e definitely not clear).